# How to power off a Debian Linux box via console

Tags: linux, debian

Brand new to Linux. I need to turn my box off and put it in my server room. The help here and everywhere seems not to work for me:

http://debianhelp.co.uk/shutdown.htm

I get:

```
lukepuplett@uktnlx01:~$ poweroff
-bash: poweroff: command not found
lukepuplett@uktnlx01:~$ shutdown
-bash: shutdown: command not found
lukepuplett@uktnlx01:~$ modprobe apm
-bash: modprobe: command not found
lukepuplett@uktnlx01:~$
```

I also tried halt, reboot, goaway, and pleasejustwork.

Comment: I laughed at pleasejustwork. Thanks `;-)`

Comment: The shutdown command is not accessible to a non-superuser by default as it's in `/sbin/` rather than in `/bin/` or `/usr/bin/`. The former is not normally added to the `$PATH` of a regular user.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You need to be root (or use `sudo`):

```
# This halts (shuts down) the computer now
sudo shutdown -h now

# This reboots the computer now
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Read the manual page for shutdown: `man shutdown` for more information.

In the link you gave, you just overlooked the sentence

> simply run as root:

Comment: Thank you. I will lookup sudo and root permissions. Why does it act like the command doesn't exist?

Comment: @LukePuplett The `shutdown` command is in the `/sbin` directory, which is not in your path. It is hence not found by bash when you're calling it while not being root. Compare `which shutdown` (no output) with `sudo which shutdown` (output is `sbin/shutdown`).

Comment: Command `halt` or `reboot` could be prefered, (at least from version 6 of Debian). As *If halt or reboot is called when the system is not in runlevel 0 or 6, in other words when it's running normally, shutdown will be invoked instead (with the -h or -r flag).* see `man halt`.

Comment: @F.Hauri In most distributions, `halt` and `reboot` are low-level commands, and `shutdown` is the high-level one. I prefer using the high level one, that takes time to run clean-up scripts, etc... in some distributions (e.g., Debian), but not all, `halt` and `reboot` do call shutdown... so what's the point? Anyway, my preference is really for `shutdown`.

Comment: Of course you're right, but as question stand clearly for a *Debian Linux box*, this could be mentioned (maybe with remark about restricted solution). At all, the test `if runlevel == 6 || runlevel == 0` could become a standard in all Linux distrib in a near futur (if not already)... ( I guess ;-)

Comment: This is no longer correct as of the Stretch release.

Comment: As of newer systemd-based distributions, you'll need to first `sudo apt install systemd-sysv` to get the symlinks back, then follow the `su && reboot` or `sudo reboot` advice.

Answer (score 12):

You need to be root (or use sudo):

To shutdow the pc use:

```
systemctl poweroff
```

To restart the pc use:

```
systemctl reboot
```

Comment: this only works when systemd is being used

Answer (score 2):

debian-11.6.0-amd64-netinst minimal with non free firmwares

Fresh installs may not have poweroff or shutdown available to basic users as bash commands.

An alternative way to shutdown is:

```
systemctl poweroff
```

My method:
Must be root

Login as root:

```
su root
```

or my fav

```
su -
```

then

```
reboot
```

Should work as normal.

This link could help others:
https://wiki.debian.org/shutdown

Comment: Is this adding anything more to the previous answers

Comment: This answer adds an important point - with just a base install, the `poweroff` and `shutdown` commands are not available. Running `systemctl poweroff` is the only option.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, and in my (Debian 7) installation

> sudo poweroff

or

> sudo shutdown

did not work. All I got was command not found.
Only after becoming root I could issue the commands.
To become root:

> su

then poweroff and shutdown works!

Answer (score 0):

`halt`, run as root, or `sudo halt` if you are on the sudoers list, should do the trick.

Comment: how to be inside sudoers list?

Comment: @gumuruh `man sudoers`, `man visudo`