# Unable to shutdown / reboot my Debian 10 server

Tags: linux, debian, terminal, shutdown, reboot

I'm trying to reboot my Debian 10 server but all I get is `command not found`.

I've tried:

```
shutdown
reboot
restart
poweroff
```

but nothing works. I found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/513596/how-to-power-off-a-debian-linux-box-via-console) thread but when I try to run any of this with `sudo` I get `bash: sudo: command not found`.
At the moment I'm logged in as root so I should have the privileges to restart the machine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe your `PATH` is empty or messed up. `/sbin/reboot` should work. If it works, do you still get `command not found` for many commands after the reboot?

Comment: Its a VM where I want to try my new coded C# apps with Mono so I don't use many commands there. I can say that apt, apt-get, su and wget works.
So I tried it with your version and it works fine on the machine itself. After the reboot it works with putty too. It was the first start after the installation. Coud whis cause the problem?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The trick on how to fix this inconvenience is to explicitly tell the `su` to set environment variable as if the user logs in directly. This is can be done by the use of `-` switch.

```
$ su -
```

Answer (score 58):

> Debian 10 has now fully switched to Systemd which means that the traditional commands to halt or reboot a system like 'shutdown -h now' or 'reboot' will not work anymore

[source](https://www.faqforge.com/linux/distributions/debian/how-to-shutdown-or-reboot-debian-10-buster/)

Starting with Debian 10, you should use the commands `systemctl poweroff` or `systemctl reboot`.

Edit: It appears the above source was partially incorrect, you can still log in as root (see answer by Eugene) to run the old commands. If you don't want to log in as root, use `systemctl`.

[source](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/ppc64el/ch08s01.en.html)

Comment: I wasn't able to get CRON to reboot my system - indeed using `systemctl reboot` in the cronjob worked.

Comment: or just `sudo apt install systemd-sysv` to get the symlinks back

Answer (score 10):

As `root` -> `systemctl poweroff` or `systemctl reboot`.

Comment: Why, what does this do, explain with more detail.

Comment: @GammaGames your edit was rejected because it substantially changed the post. Your info is good and so should be its own answer. Please post your own answer.

Comment: @music2myear thank you, the reject reasons were generic and did not seem to match your explanation. I have submitted an answer.

Answer (score 6):

As `root` -> Edit `/root/.bashrc`

Add to the end of the file:

```bash
alias reboot='systemctl reboot'
alias poweroff='systemctl poweroff'
```

Save the file and start session as root again.

Comment: or just `sudo apt install systemd-sysv` to get the symlinks back as a properly managed package

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`nano /bin/reboot`

add line: `systemctl reboot`

exit and save

`chmod` to your preffered execution level.

I'm sure there is a more elegant way to fix this but I am going to have a hard time remembering that only debian 10 requires a special reboot command.  This works for me as long as I'm in `su` first.

Answer (score 0):

Use `/sbin/shutdown [OPTIONS...] [TIME] [WALLMSG]` :)

Answer (score 0):

Use command to reboot immediately.

`reboot -f`

if above command doesn't work due to some kernel issue then you below command.

`systemctl reboot` to reboot or `systemctl poweroff` to shutdown the system.

Answer (score 0):

saya mempunyai masalah yang sama, akan tetapi saya menemukan artikel di : https://www.tembolok.id/cara-mengatasi-linux-mint-tidak-bisa-shutdown/

dengan melakukan perubahan di folder /etc/default/grub menggunakan teks editor vi / gedit, kemudian lakukan perubahan pada teks berikut:
sebelum : GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash “
sesudah : GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash acpi=force”

========================================================
I had the same problem, but I found the article at: https://www.tembolok.id/cara-mengatasi-linux-mint-tidak-bisa-shutdown/

by making changes in the /etc/default/grub folder using the text editor vi / gedit, then make changes to the following text:
before : GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash”
after : GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash acpi=force”

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dfIC.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).